# How to configure multiple auto-renewal subscription for a single app in Google Play Console and App Store Connect

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, ionic4, auto-renewable

I have developed an Ionic 4 app that allows users to create an unlimited number of groups. By default, each of the created groups has the same basic features and full features can be accessed once the user subscribes the group to a premium package (subscription per-group basis).

The premium package consists of a monthly and yearly subscription, and I managed to implement a single auto-renewal subscription which is for one group only. However, since the number of groups created is unlimited and each of the groups can be upgraded to a premium package, I did not find any reference on how to configure the multiple auto-renewable subscriptions dynamically. This is important as the billing need to be done separately for each group.

Based on Apple Developer documentation, https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

> If your app needs to offer users the ability to buy multiple subscriptions — for example, to subscribe to more than one channel in a streaming app — you can add these subscriptions to different groups. Users who buy subscriptions in multiple groups will be billed separately for each subscription.

According to the above statement, am I required to register different Subscription Group for each created group? If yes, how to do so dynamically. In the App Store Connect, when I've tried to set up the in-app purchases, they provided a reference link for multiple auto-renewal subscriptions but the site is not working anymore.

As for Google Play, I've got no clue at all from these documentations, https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs, and https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en

*Note:*

- Plugin used for the in-app purchase is Ionic Native In App Purchase 2 (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase)
- Life360 is the example of an existing app that uses the subscription method that I wanted to implement

Answer (score 0):

Neither platform allows for dynamic SKUs to be added. Apple requires you to go through a review whenever you add or edit a SKU. Because of this, what you're asking for is not possible.

The use case for Subscription Groups (for iOS) is designed for offering different subscription programs (for example, an magazine app could have a subscription for 1 magazine, and another subscription for another magazine), and within each subscription group you'd have different options (say, basic, premium, platinum) or durations (monthly, 3 monthly, annual), and the user would only be able to subscribe to one of these options within a group. Changing from 1 subscription to another within the same group applies a proration / refund for the unused time.

In this case it is probably not applicable to your use case.

I hope you found a solution that worked though. In my opinion, you may have had to go with the Consumable route, which is basically a 1 time consumable purchase, to unlock the features of the group for 1 year, but does not renew, and you'd have to prompt for renewal again in the future.